# Replace function and its derivatives

Tags: replacement, expression-manipulation

When I have a complicated expression that depends on some variable, say, $f$, the following usually works ok:

```
Expression ./ { f-> x^2 }
```

But if $f$ is a function `f[x,y]`, and `Expression` has not only terms like `f[x,y]` but also `D[ f[x,y], x]` (in markup they show up as `f^{(1,0)}[x,y]`), the above substitution would leave the derivatives unaffected

Is there a smarter way to do expression replacement that does the expected behavior with derivatives of the replaced expression?

Comment: Like this: `Derivative[1, 0][f][x, y] + f[x, y] /. f -> (#^2 &)` ?

Comment: Consider this: `Sum[Nest[#.{p, q} &, D[f[x, y], {{x, y}, k}], k], {k, 0, 2}] /. f -> (Sin[#1 + Sin[#2]] &)`.

Comment: p.s. you can also use this function: `dChange[
 Derivative[1, 0][f][x, y] + f[x, y],
 f[x, y] == x^2
 ]` from [80241](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80241/5478)

Comment: If it is only about replacement of a function this closely related, at least: [40189](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40189/5478), or [46868](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46868/5478)